# New version of ZFS for DKMS?

Tags: kernel, zfs, dkms

I have already installed zfs 2.1.5 module with everything for DKMS in /usr/src after executing following command: `apt install zfs-dkms`.

But How I can add new versions of zfs modules?

- Should I compile and build custom DKMS package from downloaded zfs source before putting folder with it into /usr/src/ with created created by myself dkms.conf file? https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Developer%20Resources/Custom%20Packages.html
- Or I can just put downloaded zfs source with make files and with created by myself dkms.conf file into /usr/src/?

I've tried to find any information about this, but found absolutely nothing.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of your very similar previous question from the day before you asked this one. If this isn't a duplicate, please edit to clarify how it's different.